# Computing Confidence Intervals Two Ways

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Below is a problem which I did. I am hoping that somebody can check it
and confirm that I did it correctly. In math, if I do a problem two different
ways I should get the same answer both ways. In this case, I do not. I would
like to know why not.

Problem:

A random sample of $20$ houses was taken from a large city to estimate
the property tax of the house population. The mean value of annual property
tax as $\$6400$, and the standard deviation was $\$800$. Find a $95\%$
confidence interval. Use the z and the t statistic and compare the two
answers.

The books answer is:

Using the z-value: $6049.4,6750.6$

Using the t-value: $6025.588,6774.412$

Answer: (a)

First I find the confidence interval using the z statistic. Let $CI_n$
be the confidence interval.
\begin{eqnarray*}
CI_n &=& \bar{x} \pm z_{ \frac{\alpha}{2} }\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \\
\alpha &=& 0.05 \\
\bar{x} &=& 6400 \\
\sigma &=& 800 \\
z_{ \frac{\alpha}{2} } &=& 1.96 \\
n &=& 20 \\
CI_n &=& 6400 \pm 1.96 \frac{800}{\sqrt{20}} \\
CI_n &=& 6400 \pm 350.61 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\newline
Let $CI_t$ be the confidence interval.
\begin{eqnarray*}
CI_t &=& \bar{x} \pm t_{ \frac{\alpha}{2},n-1 }\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} \\
\alpha &=& 0.05 \\
n &=& 20 \\
s &=& 800 \\
t_{ .025,19 } &=& -2.093 \\
CI_t &=& 6400 \pm -2.093 \frac{800}{\sqrt{20}} \\
CI_t &=& 6400 \pm 374.4 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The answer with the $z$ value assumes that the sample standard deviation is equal to the population standard deviation. In this case the (rescaled) distribution of the sample mean behaves like a normal distribution.

Comment: The answer with the $t$ value takes into account that the sample standard deviation typically differs from the population standard deviation. In this case the (rescaled) distribution of the sample mean behaves like a Student's $t$ distribution with a certain number of degrees of freedom. This distribution has larger deviations from its mean than the corresponding normal distribution, so confidence intervals constructed this way are inevitably somewhat longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer with the $z$ value assumes that the sample standard deviation is equal to the population standard deviation. In this case the (rescaled) distribution of the sample mean behaves like a normal distribution.

The answer with the $t$ value takes into account that the sample standard deviation typically differs from the population standard deviation. In this case the (rescaled) distribution of the sample mean behaves like a Student's $t$ distribution with a certain number of degrees of freedom. This distribution has larger deviations from its mean than the corresponding normal distribution, so confidence intervals constructed this way are inevitably somewhat longer.

Comment: Can you please try answering a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909908/why-sampling-without-replacement-gives-better-ci-performance)